# Node.js: Request.body undefined (with body-parser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request, body-parser

I am new to Node.js and I have been trying to post (GET method) a simple form, but it still shows that "request.body" is undefined, despite using body-parser, and having moved it above the "route declarations" as suggested by other answers in other questions.

This is the HTML: (y.html)

```
<body>
<form action="/boats" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="textField" id="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

srv.js:

```
 var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var bodyp = require("body-parser");
var app = express();


app.listen(3000);
app.use(bodyp());
app.use(express.static('index'));

app.get('/boats', function(request, response) {

    response.send("You sent: " + request.body.textField);

});
```

I just don't know where the mistake could be.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

GET request in HTTP doesn`t have body.

If you want get params from GET request, you can write

```
request.param.textField
```

instead

```
request.body.textField
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize this.